# SQL Remove non duplicate entires in a table

Tags: sql

I have a table with two columns `CountryCode CountryName`. There are duplicate entries in `countrycode`. But I want to remove the non-duplicate entires and keep the rows which are duplicates in the `countrycode` column. So I am trying to write an SQL statement to do this. I think I have to use Having but not too sure how exactly to incorporate it. Thanks

Comment: What have you until now? which SQL flavor are you using(mssql, mysql, oracle,...)?

Comment: why dont you check my answer? It only returns duplicates

Comment: If you can provide some example input and output, we can offer better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bit odd.  I was expecting you to want to remove the duplicate entries, not the other way around.  But something like this should work regardless of the database you are using:

```
delete from TableName
 where CountryCode in (select CountryCode
                         from TableName
                        group by CountryCode
                        having count(*) = 1).
```

So to be clear, the subquery:

```
select CountryCode
  from TableName
 group by CountryCode
having count(*) = 1
```

... returns rows with unique `CountryCodes`. And then the `delete` statement:

```
delete from TableName
 where CountryCode in (...)
```

... deletes those unique rows so that the only rows remaining in your table should be the ones with duplicates.

However, by your comments, it sounds like you just want a query that returns only the duplicates.  If that's the case, then just use the subquery inside a `select` statement, but modify the `having` clause to return only duplicates:

```
select *
  from TableName
 where CountryCode in (select CountryCode
                        from TableName
                       group by CountryCode
                      having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Could you explain this part `group by CountryCode
                        having count(*) = 1)`? What does it do precisely?

Comment: Because I'm grouping by `CountryCode`, for every `CountryCode`, `count(*)` returns how many rows have that same `CountryCode`.  If you have duplicates, naturally, the value will be `2` or more.  But if there aren't any duplicates, the value will be `1`.  So when I say `having count(*) = 1`, I'm essentially saying that I am only interested in the `CountryCode`s that don't have duplicates.

Comment: If this is still not clear, examine the results of this query: `select CountryCode, count(*) from TableName group by CountryCode` and pay attention to the `count(*)` values for each `CountryCode`.  That should make it clearer.

Comment: I think I get it, however unique entries of CountryCode shows, I wants it's duplicate to show, for an example lets say CountryCode USA shows up multiple times on separate rows but CountryCode CAN shows up on one row I want to remove the rows which have CAN but keep the duplicate rows of USA.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I posted.  I am removing (deleting) rows that don't have duplicates.  Did I misunderstand what you meant by "remove"?  Is it that you simply want to write a `select` statement that returns duplicate rows only, and not that you want to actually `delete` gthe non-duplicate rows?

Comment: I think you are understanding correctly, but I don't seem to getting duplicate rows to appear. I'll take a closer look though.

Comment: I edited my post. I think there may be a little bit of a misunderstanding. Hopefully that makes it clearer. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick solution, it is probablly not the fastes with alot of entries, but it works.

```
SELECT * FROM [table] AS tbl 
   WHERE countrycode IN 
        (SELECT countrycode FROM [table] WHERE tbl.countryname <> countryname)    

/* Words in uppercase are SQL Syntax */
```

> naming the first table (**`tbl`**) you can use it in the nested query

Comment: I tried it as well, but doesn't seem to work. I'm taking a closer look into it. Sorry about that.