# Delete rows that have not duplicates

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

There is a some field named `foo` in a table `bar` (Actually, it is a Hive table, but maybe it doesn't matter). I need to delete all rows, which have not duplicates by field `foo`. I.e. I should remove all rows for all possible `<val>`, that the following query return 1,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bar WHERE foo=<val>;
```

How to write the query for deleting described rows?

Comment: Maybe you can try to see the link below it might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32930051/sql-remove-non-duplicate-entires-in-a-table

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Google clear concise phrasings of what you want. Please read [ask] and the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 1):

Most SQL dialects allow a pattern like this:

```
DELETE
    b
FROM
    bar b
    INNER JOIN (SELECT foo FROM bar GROUP BY foo HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) x ON x.foo = b.foo;
```

I'm not sure if that works for Hive, but it might get you started?